# Help with a possible Cauchy Proof?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Hello Mathematics community! I have this problem I've been stuck on for a while:

Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence, and {$L_1, L_2,L_3,...$} are partial limits of $a_n$. Assume that $L_n$-> $L$. Prove that $L$ is also a partial limit for $a_n$.

So, at first glance, I am thinking I want to prove this acts like a Cauchy Sequence, that the head of a sequence doesn't determine the limit, it's the tail. I am also thinking maybe the Bolzano-Wierstrass Theorem might help (We can extract a convergent sub-sequence that always converges for any sequence).

I have no clue as to where to start, and I am not even sure what I should be trying to do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are partial limits?

Comment: I do not know what a "partial limit" is either, but I am guessing you mean that $L_i$ is a value for which there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_i[k]}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to it.  In that case you know there are points of the sequence that get arbitrarily close to $L_i$ (for each $i$), so use them to find points that get arbitrarily close to $L$.

Comment: I have no clue what a partial limit is either. This question was listed on my assignment, and never have I also have heard of a partial limit, which is why I am confused as to what to do.

Comment: You should include the complete assignment or ask your professor or tutor. Partial limit is surely an uncommon notation.

Comment: This is the whole assignment. There are other problems involving proving the ratio test,root test, integral test, and alternating series test. This is the last problem, and I copied it word for word, notation for notation.

Comment: That sounds more like series than sequence. Than it would be partial sum. You should ask your tutor.